# How can I send an ambiguous request in Rails Test Case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes

I have the following definitions in my routes:

```
resources :demands { resources: :solutions }
resources :technologies { resources: :solutions }
```

and in my controller test, I want to send two requests:

```
Get /demands/d123/solutions?technology_id=t123
Get /technologies/t123/solutions?demand_id=d123
```

But they both match the same invokes(in SolutionsControllerTest):

```
get :index, demand_id: d123, technology_id: t123
```

it match the first definition in routes.rb, which is

```
resources :demands { resources: :solutions }
```

How should I send both requests in distinct methods?

Comment: Shouldn't the second request be tested in its own controller spec?

Answer (score 0):

Functional (Controller) tests fake the whole request stage. 
Instead of invoking a rails server and sending an actual request `ActionController::TestCase` just creates a Request object and passes it to a controller instance. This lets you poke around in way which is not possible in an integration test due to the server and test running in separate processes.

Instead you would want to use a integration test and actually send a HTTP request so that it goes through the routing component:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AmbiguousRoutesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "is /demands/d123/solutions?technology_id=t123 ambigous?" do
     get "/demands/d123/solutions?technology_id=t123"
     # @todo write assertions about the response
  end 
end
```